# how to set hook for specific application before its starting

Tags: c++, c, winapi, hook

I have two programs : A.exe and B.exe.
MAY BE B.exe invokes system function ( e.g void foo() ).

In the code of A.exe program I create process of B.exe program and wait till it's finished.
I want FORCE B.exe to TERMINATE if it invokes foo() function.

I know that it's possible to implement using GLOBAL hooks, but it's not clear. GLOBAL hooks can influence on other working processes and make them unstable (e.g. Skype checks if system functions are not changes and it crashes if it's not right).

Also I want to set hook BEFORE starting B.exe. Otherwise there will be loosed/non cached foo() invocations.

Answer (score 1):

You can't block API calls using hooks. You *can* inject DLLs that then proceed to manually hook API calls, typically by modifying the import stub. A better solution would be to use the debug API, CreateProcess with DEBUG_PROCESS, followed by a WaitForDebugEvent/ContinueDebugEvent loop.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/writing_debugger_1.aspx covers windows debuggers decently.